# SSRS report does not work with multiple parameters

Tags: ssrs, parameter

My data set has the following where clause:

```
WHERE a11.PDPOID LIKE '%' + @POID + '%'
```

My parameter `@POID` properties are set to single value.  The report works, but if I change the parameter properties to allow multiple values then I get an error:

> Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSetDtRcvd'. incorrect syntax near ','.

[image: A screen shot of the report's parameter properties]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512105/passing-multiple-values-for-a-single-parameter-in-reporting-services)?  It looks like the values for the parameter are passed as a comma-delimited list, which will break if you splice it into a `LIKE` predicate.

Comment: It seems like you are going to provide a list of values then why do you use LIKE '%' + @POID + '%' ? For the list of values you need to do WHERE a11.PDPOID IN (@POID).

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by changing your dataset query to an expression and use the `Join` operator on the multi-valued parameter, for example, your expression would look like

```
= "Select * " &
  "from table t " &
  "where a11.PDPOID LIKE '%" & Join(Parameters!TestParm.Label, "%' OR a11.PDPOID LIKE 
  '%") & "%'"
```

Replace the `Select * from table t` with your query.

Answer (score 1):

You're running into this problem because of the difference in how SSRS passes multi-value parameters when using a text query vs. using a stored procedure for your dataset.

When using a text query, the parameter is actually replaced with a literal list of strings before executing the query, e.g. `PDPOID IN (@PDPOID)` is translated to `PDPOID IN ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc')` (assuming you've selected 'aaa', 'bbb', and 'ccc').

For a stored procedure, the selected values are turned into a comma-separated list, and passed as a single string/character parameter. So if your stored procedure has a parameter named `@PDPOID`, then the parameter would be set to the single value 'aaa,bbb,ccc'.

The easiest way to make this work is to change your report to use a stored procedure for the query, then use the `STRING_SPLIT` function (or a suitable homebrew string splitting function if you're running a version older than SQL Server 2016). For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE POReport
    @POID varchar(max)
AS

SELECT *
FROM POs a11
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT p.value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@POID,',') p WHERE a11.PDPOID LIKE '%' + p.value + '%')
```